# Command line applications don't launch from menu

Tags: release-loki, slingshot, app-shortcuts

After installation of some software that in general run in terminal, like vim or htop, their shortcuts appear in application menu, which is nice and correct.

But the issue I have is that when I choose e.g. htop from applications menu, it doesn't launch at all.

Have anyone faced such issue? I've searched this site, elementary's bug tracker and google, but haven't even found anyone else having this issue.

Don't know where I could start investigating this, so if you think I should add some particular logs etc., just let me know in the comment.

I'm working on Loki 0.4.1.

Comment: You could check the .desktop files associated with these apps. Check the line "Terminal:", make sure it is set to - true.

Comment: @SeanPatterson Yes it is set to true. I've just checked.

Answer (score 1):

Still don't have any idea where to look for real reason of the issue, but I've found a workaround.

For example for htop application, in file `/usr/share/applications/htop.desktop` I've changed lines:

```
Terminal=true
Exec=htop
```

to:

```
Terminal=false
Exec=x-terminal-emulator -e htop
```

Now it works. I'm aware that it's not like it should be, as it requires to fix every terminal application separately, so if anyone has a real solution, I still would be happy to know about it.